# Unable to connect to network after factory reset

Tags: google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi, connection-issues, factory-reset

Today I did a factory reset on my phone (Galaxy y GT-S5360T) to attempt to free up some space (it worked, thankfully) and now I can't seem to connect to any wifi network. I am currently running the stock ROM which is Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread and I am also rooted.

I also noticed after the reset the Google Play store had been replaced by the Android Market. I don't have anything against the Android Market, but I do prefer Google Play.

Does anyone know how to fix these problems?
Thanks in advance

Edit: When my phone tries to connect to a wifi network, the status reports that it is 'Obtaining IP Address" and it just ends there. Nothing else happens. I have heard in more than one place that I can create a static IP address and that will fix the problem but I have no idea how I can do this. It would be much appreciated if someone could point me towards a tutorial on how to do this, as I have no idea. I have also tried a factory reset again again and this still did not fix the problem.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and provide a few more details on your network problem: step by step, what are you doing and what is happening? What can you see in the WiFi menu (status of the APN you try to connect to)? Maybe you entered the wrong WiFi password? If it's not that trivial, can you connect your device to your computer and run `adb logcat` to check the system logs for errors? As for the "Market": This issue will resolve itself as soon as you got your network running, as it will auto-update to Google Play again.

Comment: This may be quite obvious, but what exactly is `adb logcat` and what does it entail?

Comment: First, try restrating the phone, this might fix most of the problems. If it doesn't work then continue with `logcat`.

Connect your phone to your PC using USB and run `adb logcat` in terminal(cmd window). (adb and fastboot can be obtained from this [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=42407269).

After this follow the logcat guide [here.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2303834)

Comment: Use this app to pull the logs: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat

Comment: Or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat

Comment: @ce4 If he's got no network connection he cannot install from playstore (which is why I instead brought up `adb logcat`). Levi: Take a look at [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) for a quick starter without unnecessary ballast. If you do not plan to develop apps, that minimal install is all you will need. Also check QtADB (linked there) for a graphical interface which might prove helpful to you.

Comment: Full ack, my bad. :-) He could download it from F-Droid, put it on a SDcard using his PC and side load it. Alternative Download links for logcat viewer apps: https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=logcat